# Intelij: Highlist usages in plain text files?

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, highlight

Is there a setting in InteliJ to make it highlight usages of a word that is currently selected in plain text files similar to what Notepad and Sublime text editors do and what InteliJ does in java?

Help guide https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/highlighting-usages.html has `Highlight usages of element at caret` but that setting doesn't seem to change anything in plain text files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij IDEA highlight all occurrences of selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373402/intellij-idea-highlight-all-occurrences-of-selected-text)

Answer (score 1):

To highlight all occurrences of a word in plain text, select the word and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. This will open a search header filled with the selected word and all matches will be highlighted.

This is not exactly *usages* highlighting (since there is no real context in a plain text file), but it does what you want.

Comment: Yea that's what I have been doing... But it is much less convenient

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Edit > Find > Highlight Usages in File* `Ctrl + Shift + F7`.

This highlights all usages of selected text using the Find window.