# Intellij IDEA highlight all occurrences of selected text

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently, intellij highlights all occurrences of the word under the caret. How can I change it so that it doesn't do that, and instead will highlight all occurrences **only** when I select the word (eg: similar to sublime text) ?

Answer (score 20):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201-browsewordatcaret

From the plugin description:

> Allows to easily browse next/previous word at caret and highlight
> other appearances of selected word.

I'm using it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Does it highlight words under caret or selected words? Because only the latter works for me. Maybe I miss sth.

Comment: It only works for words, not for any selected text.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me in IntelliJ 2018.2.3:

1. Disable [automatic highlighting of usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/highlighting-usages.html#d1052877e24) by unchecking:

   ```
   Preferences | Editor | General | Highlight usages of element at caret
   ```
2. Add [mouse shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enter-mouse-shortcut-dialog.html) for Highlight Usages in File:

   ```
   Preferences | Keymap | Main menu | Edit | Find | Highlight Usages in File
   ```

My mouse shortcut was: `Shift + Control + Double Click`

Comment: will this work if I highlight a word not using a mouse? Eg: select word from keyboard?

Comment: @Vic If it helps, I use Ctrl-Shift-F7 to do it that manually.  On the pro-side of doing it manually, you can do it to multiple different selections one after the other and have them all be highlighted.

Comment: I really want the same behavior as sublime, just select text and it'll automatically highlight all occurrences, no extra keys/shortcuts

Comment: So, it seems like this is not possible currently: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000775599-How-to-highlight-all-occurrences-on-selecting-word-instead-of-under-caret-

Comment: in 2021 the function is located there: `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Editing` -> `Highlight on Caret Movement` -> `Usages of element at caret`

Comment: Does not work in html or text editor. Would be nice to avoid having to search in file all the time in html files.

Comment: Very nice native functionality, unfortunately only applies to "usages" not just plain text matches

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Highlight on Caret Movement -> Usages of element at caret

Comment: Does not work. Works in certain environment only like java or js.

Answer (score -3):

I am using Webstorm 2021.2 at the moment and this feature is working. Just for your information. Hope you also already updated to the latest.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29753675)