# How to illuminate word under caret everywhere else in the markdown?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

I use IntelliJ for my blog based on markdown files. I miss code-like highlighting, where all identical words get automatically illuminated everywhere else in that file. Similar to how identical functions or variables are highlighted under caret placement.

For example, if my file content is "The quick brown fox jumps over the brown dog" and my caret is currently at "brown" or "the" -- two words should be illuminated.

How to configure IntelliJ to automatically highlight all identical words in a markdown file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a more thorough research, I found a plugin named `BrowseWordAtCaret` [[1](https://github.com/minman/browse-word-at-caret)][[2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201-browsewordatcaret)]. It is the closest thing to my use case.

> This plugin allows to easily browse next/previous word at caret and highlight other appearances of selected word.

Also see related questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373402/intellij-idea-highlight-all-occurrences-of-selected-text) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084488/intelij-highlist-usages-in-plain-text-files).

Answer (score 0):

You can point the caret at the needed word in the editor and perform `Edit | Find Usages | Highlight Usages in File`

- `Ctrl + Shift + F7` (Windows/Linux)
- `⇧ + ⌘ + F7` (macOS)

Comment: That is not automatically, is it?